# Relationship Field ACF Repeater Badly Needed

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data

if (have_rows('star_role')):
// loop through the rows of data
    while (have_rows('star_role')):
        the_row();


        $myposts = get_sub_field('star_location'); // This is a relationship field
        if ($myposts):?>
<ul>
        <?php foreach ($myposts as $post_object):?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>"> 
                <?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID);?>
                </a>
            </li>

                <?php the_sub_field('as_on',$post_object);?> / i think this is the line i want to get the specific data same thing below.
                <?php the_sub_field('role' ,$post_object);?> / also this one


         <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

         <?php endif;
    endwhile;
else:
// no rows found
endif;

?>
```

Guys! I want to get the current role of specific relationship field like for example.

> Actor 1 - As of "Ben"  - "Main Role"

> Actor 2 - As of "Kacy" - "Supporting Role"

Now, When i'm in post of actor 1 i want to show only the "Ben" and "MainRole" Only i dont want to show the details about Actor 2.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you will look through every actor. This is caused by the `foreach`.

**EDIT**
Here you have a code example (not tested) based on the documentation. ([Read here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/#template-usage))

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data

if (have_rows('star_role')) :
    // loop through the rows of data
    while (have_rows('star_role')) :
        the_row();


        $myposts = get_sub_field('star_location'); // This is a relationship field
        if ($myposts) : ?>

            <a href="<?php echo esc_html( $myposts->post_permalink ); ?>">
                <?php echo esc_html( $myposts->post_title ); ?>
            </a>


            <?php the_sub_field('as_on', $post_object); ?> / i think this is the line i want to get the specific data same thing below.
            <?php the_sub_field('role', $post_object); ?> / also this one
            < <?php endif;
        endwhile;
    else :
    // no rows found
    endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. i think thats very hard for me as beginners. maybe can you show me some sample code and i will try to learn it

Comment: Not working but big thanks i try several times finding the solution but no luck